Settin up a macro with ImageJ
I am trying to set up a macro in imagej but I am unfamiliar with the language
This is my script :
String directory = "dts/";
String[] list = getFileList(directory);

ArrayList<String> meanValuesList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
open(directory + list[i]);
  run("Find Maxima...", "noise=0 output=[Point Selection]");
  run("Measure");
  meanValue = getResult("Mean", 0);
  meanValuesList.add(list[i] + ": " + meanValue);
    close();
}

for (j = 0; j < meanValuesList.size(); j++) {
    print(meanValuesList.get(j));
}

This is the error : '.' expected in line 1:
Thank you for your help
I need my script to work, so I need to solve the problem

ImageJ macros are not Java code. The first line of your code would be directory = "dts/";, the second list = getFileList(directory);. The 3rd line may be meanValuesList = newArray(list.length);.

You may want to try the build-in editor while writing macros. It'll guide you nicely to stick to the correct 'grammar' as macros really are not Java as @tevemadar mentioned.
Try this:
directory="dts/";
list=getFileList(directory);

meanValuesList=newArray();

for ( i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    open(directory + list[i]);
    run("Find Maxima...", "noise=0 output=[Point Selection]"); 
// noise=0 is very little noise. In most cases, that may yield too many hits.
    run("Measure");
    meanValue = getResult("Mean", 0); // This gets you only the mean of the first Maximum
// if you want the manes of all Maxima try permutating through the Results table
    for (j = 0; j < nResults; j++) {
        meanValue=getResult("Mean", j);
// Either print them right here,
        //print(meanValue);
// and/or collect them in meanValuesList 
        meanValuesList=Array.concat(meanValuesList, meanValue);
    }
    close();
// anyhow, you need to process your meanValuesList for each image, meaning inside of the outer for-loop.
    //for (j = 0; j < meanValuesList.length; j++) {
    //  print(meanValuesList[j]);
    //}
// or
    Array.print(meanValuesList);
// or what-ever you meant to do with the means.
}

